# How do i show spanish in orange and english in blue?

Tags: support

I tried using html tags, but the tags did not work.

```
<h1 style="background-color:DodgerBlue;">quiero comer fruta cruda. Por ejemplo, apples.</h1>         

<p style="background-color:Tomato;">want I eat raw fruit. For example, apples.</p>
```

quiero comer fruta cruda. Por ejemplo, apples.         
want I eat raw fruit. For example, apples.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange markdown [doesn't admit colors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230019/351283), so basically you can't.  There's **bold** and *italics* and ***both bold and italics***.  And there's

## Headers

### Of

#### Different

##### Sizes,

> quoted text,

> spoiler text,

and you can copy/paste unicode   ️.  See the [markdown help page](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

If it's necessary to add colors, you can do so via an image.  I wouldn't recommend this as it makes the text less accessible and unsearchable (plaintext is better).

On some sites there are workarounds, like math.SE where [you can use MathJax to color LaTeX code](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23337/91818), but not here.